# Is there any other compiler like typescript which compile to javascript

Tags: javascript

How many language compilers are made till now which converts its language to javascript one i know is typescript any other like that? I just want to know for my knowledge so if possible can i get a whole list of such compilers...

Comment: This is not about solving a concrete programming issue, so it's off-topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: sorry if it is a wrong topic to be post but i thought we can put questions related to computer science to gain knowledge from experts , i am extremely sorry if this question was out of topic or as you says not a problem solving question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this list https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-js
It looks like there are a lot.

Comment: wow it is really a big list but which of this is in trends or lets  says are in used by developers?

Comment: As far as I know the most popular ones are typescript/flow, elm, clojurescript and of course coffeescript.